# vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:678

Tags: laravel

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `product_catagories` (`catagory_name`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Electronics, 2021-04-25 14:32:59, 2021-04-25 14:32:59))

How Can I solved this problem on a live server

Comment: Please post the code as well in order to resolve this issue. I.e. Controllers, Models and your blade code.

Answer (score 0):

Check your 'id' structure on your sql.
You got an error because 'id' field' doesn't have default value.

[image: Check this]

Also Make sure AUTO_INCREMENT checked